# Using if else statements with arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement

I want to create an array in C# that holds a bunch of food items.

```
isafood = [ "apple","pear","grape"];

if(item == isafood){

    apple / pear /grape
}
else
{

}
```

then i want to do an if statement to see if variable item equals one of the food items in the list.

Comment: Use a foreach loop and check if i is equal to the item. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/using-foreach-with-arrays

Answer (score 1):

You have to check each item in the array to see if it matches....

with Linq you can do

```
if(isafood.Any(i => i==item))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isafood.IndexOf(item) > -1)
{
    //...
}
```